# DateTimePicker is clearing date by just opening the calendar

Tags: angularjs, ui.bootstrap

When I click on the `datetimepicker` button it clears the date.

```
'use strict';

app.directive('defaultDate', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'app/directives/default-date.html',
        scope: {
            onChange: '&',
            obj: '='
        },
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.alterou = function () {
                $scope.onChange()
            }

            $scope.openCalendar = function (e) {
                e.preventDefault()
                e.stopPropagation()
                $scope.obj = { isOpen: true };
            };
        }
    }
})
```

```html
<p class="input-group">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-change='alterou()' datetime-picker="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" ng-model="obj.date" is-open="obj.isOpen" />
  <span class="input-group-btn">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="openCalendar($event, prop)"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i></button>
  </span>
</p>
```

I would expect that the calendar shall not clear the date by just opening it.

Comment: Can you create a JSFiddle where your problem can be reproduced? Some of us might want to play around with the issue before answering.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is this line in your `$scope.openCalendar` function:

```
$scope.obj = { isOpen: true };
```

You are setting `$scope.obj` to an object with a single property of `isOpen`. What you should be doing here is:

```
$scope.obj.isOpen = true;
```

That way the value of `$scope.obj.date` will be preserved.